# C# Winforms PropertyGrid and ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, reflection, propertygrid, errorprovider

I'm working on extending the errorprovider to the propertygrid and treeview controls.  I found a very helpful post at: [Example](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/2008-06/msg02673.html)
 detailing how to add the errorprovider to a propertygrid, and it works very well.  My question is how did the author know that IPropertyValueUIService is the interface that the propertygrid uses to display the icon and tooltip.  I have used Reflector to dissassemble the propertygrid and IPropertyValueUIService and I don't see any relationship.

This is for my own edification as a programmer as well as trying to extend the errorprovider to a treeview.

Thanks in advance,
dhysong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing partly from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.ipropertyvalueuiservice.aspx)?

Or from reflector; find IPropertyValueUIService, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and expand "Used By", and you can see how it is used by `PropertyGridInternal.PropertyDescriptorGridEntry`.

Comment: Are you the same Marc Gravell that posted that explanation?  I see that MSDN documentaton on IPropertyValueUIService is pretty clear, but I don't see how I get to IPropertyValueUIService from the propertygrid documentation.

Comment: PropertyGrid is primarily a consume of System.ComponentModel and PropertyDescriptor; the linked documentation discusses that. The fact is that System.ComponentModel is very large, and even though it is (generally) well documented, there are some gaps - it is **possible** this link is in a gap. Or maybe it is there and we just  haven't seen it.

Comment: I was wrong.  I can't get to IPropertyValueUIService from propertygrid in reflector.  I do see that "used by" has PropertyGrid + PropertyGridServiceProvider, so I can infer that PropertyGridServiceProvider implements IPropertyValueUIService.  

Many thanks Marc for the initial code and this explanation as well.